# Network interface configuration on Debian 6 (No DHCPOFFERS received)

Tags: networking, debian, dhcp

I am trying to configure an interface to allow internet connection on a home server which runs Debian 6 x86.

The server is behind a router which has DHCP enabled. The router IP is `192.168.1.1` with netmask `255.255.255.0`.

I have so far tried configuring the connection via `/etc/network/interfaces` using the official Debian [docs](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Using_DHCP_to_automatically_configure_the_interface).

My current `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Once I saved this configuration, I ran `/etc/init.d/networking restart`, however, it seems like `dhclient` is unable to connect. The output given is:

```
DHCPRELEASE on eth0 to 192.168.1.1 port 67
send_packet: Network is unreachable
send_packet: please consult README file regarding broadcast address.
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
done.
```

The output of `route -n` is empty. (not sure if that is relevant)

I also tried troubleshooting the connection by ensuring that the cable is connected to the server, as well as that the router isn't malfunctioning (no issues with the other devices connected to it). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming a completely bone-stock Debian 6 install with no firewall apps configured or IPTables rule changes, your router is probably busted or your cable is bad.

Comment: @Magellan, the install isn't new, but I don't have firewall packages or any iptables rules. Regarding the hardware, I've tested both the cable and the router - they seem to work with other devices. All I remember is changing the router address from 10.0.0.0 to 192.168.0.0, but I don't think this could be the issue as other devices worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

instead of

> auto eth0

try

> auto eth0
>
> allow-hotplug eth0

**allow-hotplug** starts the interface when the kernel detects a hotplug event from the interface while **auto** starts the interface on the system start.

I'm sure but I think a DHCP release is a hotplug event.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I tried that, no success. I also did a bit more troubleshooting: to make sure the NIC is fine, I tried to connect without dhcp and set my address, gateway, netmask etc. to the ones given to me by my ISP (the address is static) - it worked like a charm. It seems that the issue is exactly with the interface and/or DHCP configuration.

Comment: Hi. If I was you (& assuming that you haven't already tried it) I would firstly reboot the router & secondly make sure that it's not using fixed leases. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: P.S Notable is "send_packet: Network is unreachable" it usually a sign that the NIC is not doing it's thing.

Comment: Well, I already tried rebooting and releasing. Also, I'm not getting the send_packet error anymore - it just appeared at the time I was posting, it is no longer present, though.